# Vimscript - Mapping functions

Tags: vim

Let's say I have a function give me ASCII value of a character that is passed as an argument and call it AsciiFunc (It's late and I can't think of creative names). Is it possible to define a single mapping which calls AsciiFunc and passes to it the character typed. For eg. if the function is mapped to `<leader>a` then pressing `<leader>af` will call the function AsciiFunc and pass 'f' as a parameter?

Just to avoid confusion, I know that `ga` gives the ascii and other information of the character under the cursor, that is not what I'm looking for. I'm looking for a way to avoid having to create multiple mappings one each for every possible value that AsciiFunc can take as an argument.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can call `getchar()` function inside `AsciiFunc()`. It'll wait for input.

Comment: You mean map `<leader>a` to `:call AsciiFunc()` and have a getchar() inside AsciiFunc?